# Nested object in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nested, vue-component

I have json object and i don't know how it looks, it can be nested. How to display this object with nested objects as li elements. I try to find and I can't find proper answer.

Comment: `i don't know how it looks` - neither do we

Comment: I want to display an object, and i dont know how it will be look like, it can be like just 2 properties or complicated nested object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first is the Object everytime different or is it always the same Object?

If it is always the same nestet Object you can print it to the  console using `console.log("my nested Object", nestedObject")`

If it's structure is everytime different you have to write yourself a parser to write it into an object where you know the structure of your Object and then you can simply print it as li using v-for or multiple nested v-for loops dependend on your Object.

Comment: `multiple nested v-for loops` how deep? 2? 3? does it depend on the object? How can you write enough nested loops to cater for all possible objects?

Comment: Depends on your object, for that i would suggest parsing first and putting the unknown nested object into a known one

Comment: Or putting it indo an array, then the object depth does not matter anymore.

Comment: Could you give me an example of an object you want to display and how you want to display it?

Comment: I'm not the OP - he's approved your answer - I was thinking of my own circumstance :p